# Difference between logs in logcat view in ddms & those obtained using adb logcat on console

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, logcat, android-logcat

There are two ways to obtain logs for android:

1. Use the `logcat-view` in DDMS prespective in eclipse. Pros - various
   filters can be applied on the logs.
2. Print logs to a file using `adb logcat` command on console.

I was wondering if the logs obtained using both the methods are same?

If not, what is the difference (apart from filtering ease on ddms).
I mean, which logs should be used and when?

(I did not find both the ways giving the same logs)

Comment: both are same until you not supply custom tag.

Comment: there is no difference, you should use logcat view in ddms as you can apply filter for relevant logs.